# Upload Files to a particular Folder in Ruby On Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using working on a particular module in Ruby on Rails, where I want to upload files to a particular folder. If it's possible, would you please share some examples which may help me achieve this functionality?

Comment: I tried achieving this functionality with the help of paperclip gems but its for uploading in database but i want to upload file to a custom path in computer.

Comment: try this link http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dharam mentioned. you can use paperclip. The working example you can find here

[demo](http://code.runnable.com/UnnhcBiQoFhwAAEb/how-to-upload-files-using-paperclip-for-ruby-on-rails)

If you want to specify folder path where the attachments should move. you need to write this in your model

```
has_attached_file :attachment, :path => ":rails_root/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

After this all your attachments will be seen in attachments folder in your Application root

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but i want the file to be downloaded or stored in folder of computer not in database.How's it possible??? By the way...are you also a Ruby on Rails developer???

Comment: i want that file should be uploaded in custom directory which i specify at the time of uploading.

Comment: Have edited the answer for including path to store folder in application folder

Comment: rest of the code is same...as u mentioned in the demo......we only need to put the above code in model or any other changes needed????

Comment: but i think this approach is not good..because i want the application to behave independently...because it will create problem when we host our application in live....so i want user to specify his own path at the time of uploading his file.....and path should be Operating System independent....

Comment: The Code above is Operating systems independent. it is Application specific. the folder is present within Application directory

Comment: Thanks a lot...,will try it out  :)

Comment: I'm working on a module in ruby on rails 4,where i have two forms in which i have two forms,and i want  to display the data of another form in redirected page..for example ill fill Appraiser Goal form and on clicking on next the form for Appraisee Goal should display on top of it,which i have filled earlier.

Answer (score 1):

`paperclip` gem supports multiple storage options, including file storage.

Refer to [FileSystem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/Filesystem) for more info.

Other gem you can look into is [`carrierwave`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir...will u please share any link where i may get details regarding this.

Comment: i'm new in this..so please help

Comment: I have already included links to FileSystem storage for paperclip as well as carrierwave. What other links are you expecting?